# Children of Firebase database path are not attached by DataSnapshot for loop (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem in my android project which is connected to firebase. I want to display the child elements of my firebase database in a recyclerview. For this i created the following code to save the data in an arraylist. But there is a problem with attaching the childs of the path - the code does not add the items to the list :|. Is there an error in the reference to the database or an error in the eventlistener?

```
private void loadDataOutfitDetail(String userID, String weatherToday){
        // set the firebase path for loading the images of the clothes
        databaseRefOutfit = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID + "/" + weather1 + "/ID1" + "/details");

        // clear the list for showing only the filtered weather
        uploadDetails.clear();

        // get data out
        databaseRefOutfit.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    UploadDetails upload = postSnapshot.getValue(UploadDetails.class);
                    // add items to list
                    uploadDetails.add(upload);
                }

                // update the recyclerview
                outfitAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

My Firebase database has the following structure:

```
USERID
   outfit
      weather1
         ID1
            details
               desciption: Here is a description
               name: MyName
            imageUpperPart
               name: image1
         ID2
            details
               description: Here is another description
               name: NewName
            imageUpperPart
               name: image2
```

How can I add the values of the details node to the arraylist uploadDetails?

Thank you keved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the reference to the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID).child("outfit").child("weather1").child("ID1").child("details");
```

You are missing the node `outfit` in your reference.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a mistake in my code :/ 
But it is still not working ... i receive the message com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.forlook.UploadOutfit and the activity loads every second new :( Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the for loop

Comment: It does not work for me :| 
But now i changed the structure of my database, that solved my problem :)